# Blender 2.8 Command Line: Errors on running script

Tags: python, scripting, error, command-line, windows

I am looking to run my python scripts using the command line. So far, I have confirmed I can open blender using the command line, and I can open a specific file as well.

The issue comes when I attempt to load a script. I seem to always get the following error:

```
OSError: Python file "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\genererate_tears.py" could not be opened: No such file or directory
```

I would imagine I have some missing reference, but I have not been able to find anything where someone else solved this issue.

Here's what my my command line looks like

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender -b H:\Blender3d\ScriptingPractice\scriptingpractice.blend -P genererate_tears.py
```

Essentially:

[Blender.exe] _ [blender file with script] _ [syntax to run python] _ [python script isnide of .blend file]

I have tested the rest of it without the script part, and not running it in the background, so I'm pretty confident it's just the script reference

- and according to this post https://developer.blender.org/T60330 it isn't an issue with older versions?
  [image: ref screenshot command line]

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just a typo? `genererate_tears.py` should probably be `generate_tears.py`, unless the actual file name is misspelled.

Comment: I've re-read your question and noticed that apparently you're not storing the script outside of your .blend file, because you say "[python script isnide of .blend file]". In order to for the command to work the script needs to exist at the path given in the error message. If there is no file at the `C:\Program File\Blender Foundation\Blender\genererate_tears.py` then Blender can't open it. You can store the script wherever you want, but then you need to use an absolute path for the `-P` flag (it doesn't have to be relative to Blender's install dir).

Comment: @RobertGützkow I'm not familiar with storing the path. Would it be appropriate to save my scritp as a text file, and change the .txt to .py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou @RobertGützkow for your help!

The solution was true that I needed to have a python-specific file (outside of blender) that I could run.

To do this I

1) created a new Text.txt file
2) named it the same name as my script (optional)
3) copied and pasted the code into the text.txt file
4) rename the text.txt --> text.py
5) add the text.py file path to the code.

Here's what mine looked like :
(with the command prompt pointed at blender)

**C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>**

```
blender H:\Blender3d\ScriptingPractice\scriptingpractice.blend -P H:\Blender3d\ScriptingPractice\genererate_tears.py
```